# Powershell Progress Bar for printing files

Tags: powershell

I am trying to print all TEXT files in a directory and display a progress bar. 
 This is because there can often be hundreds of files in the directory.

Currently I have a mash up of script that I am trying to piece together.  I found the bits in separate areas, but I cant seem to figure out how to make it work together.

```
$Directory = "C:\Temp\Test"
$FileType = '*.txt'


Write-Host $FileType ' Files in Directory: '(Get-ChildItem -path $Directory -recurse -include *.txt).count


$TotalSteps = (Get-ChildItem -path $Directory -recurse -include *.txt).count
$Step       = 1
$StepText   = "Setting up print job"

$StatusText = '"Step $($Step.ToString().PadLeft($TotalSteps.Count.ToString().Length)) of $TotalSteps | $StepText"'
$StatusBlock = [ScriptBlock]::Create($StatusText)
$Task        = "Creating Progress Bar Script Block for Print Job"

Write-Progress -Id $Id -Activity $Activity -Status (&amp; $StatusBlock) -CurrentOperation $Task -PercentComplete ($Step / $TotalSteps * 100)

Get-ChildItem -path $Directory -recurse -include *.txt | ForEach-Object {Start-Process -FilePath $_.fullname -Verb Print -PassThru | %{sleep 7;$_} | kill }
```

Comment: What is the output of the progress bar showing when you run this? Also, why are you defining `$StatusBlock` as a ScriptBlock?

Comment: Sorry... I just pasted all the script Im looking at.  I guess I should have mentioned that.  My initial component was the last line:Get-ChildItem -path $Directory -recurse -include *.txt | ForEach-Object {Start-Process -FilePath $_.fullname -Verb Print -PassThru | %{sleep 7;$_} | kill }

Comment: Everything else pasted above that foreach print line was stuff I was just trying to make work

Comment: Please feel free to suggest a simpler method to achieve my goal.  Thanks for looking at this!

Comment: Bueller?  Bueller?  :)